# GeoServer Image Mosaic JDBC

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, image-pyramids

I'm running GeoServer 2.15.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 with the latest `ubuntugis-unstable` release packages (GDAL 3.0.2, PostGIS 3.0.0) and cannot get the Image Mosaic *.jar to load. I followed the instructions of https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaicjdbc.html

The pertinent files are loaded into `/usr/local/geonode/geoserver/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib`

```bsh
gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-21.2.jar
gt-imagepyramid-21.2.jar
```

The pertinent xml configurations are in `/var/lib/geoserver_data/coverages` and are

```bsh
connect.pgraster.xml.inc  ned_13.pgraster.xml  ned_1m.pgraster.xml
mapping.pgraster.xml.inc  ned_19.pgraster.xml  ned_1.pgraster.xml
```

The contents of `connect.pgraster.xml.inc` are

```xml
<connect>
   <dstype value="DBCP"/>
   <username value="geonode"/>
   <password value="password"/>
   <jdbcUrl value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spl_gis"/>
   <driverClassName value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
   <maxActive value="10"/>
   <maxIdle value="0"/>
</connect>
```

The contents of `mapping.pgraster.xml.inc` are

```xml
<spatialExtension name="pgraster"/>
<mapping>
    <masterTable name="MOSAIC" >
        <coverageNameAttribute name="NAME"/>
        <maxXAttribute name="maxX"/>
        <maxYAttribute name="maxY"/>
        <minXAttribute name="minX"/>
        <minYAttribute name="minY"/>
        <resXAttribute name="resX"/>
        <resYAttribute name="resY"/>
        <tileTableNameAtribute  name="TileTable" />
    </masterTable>
    <tileTable>
        <blobAttributeName name="rast" />
    </tileTable>
</mapping>
```

The contents of `ned_1.pgraster.xml` are

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ImageMosaicJDBCConfig [
    <!ENTITY mapping PUBLIC "mapping"  "mapping.pgraster.xml.inc">
    <!ENTITY connect PUBLIC "connect"  "connect.pgraster.xml.inc">
]>

<config version="1.0">
    <coverageName name="ned_1"/>
    <coordsys name="EPSG:4269"/>
    <!-- interpolation 1 = nearest neighbor, 2 = bipolar, 3 = bicubic -->
    <scaleop  interpolation="1"/>
    <axisOrder ignore="false"/>
          &mapping;
          &connect;
</config>
```

The above files should only be needed once the ImageMosaicJDBC is selected. As such, these are untested...

Once `tomcat` has been restarted the two *.jar modules do not appear in the Server Status - Modules list neither does the `ImageMosaicJDBC` option appear when adding a new data source.

GeoServer accesses the distro PostgreSQL 12 just fine for all of the vector data. So, I'm not sure what/which config I'm missing. Any pointers?

**EDIT**
There are a number of warnings during startup that aren't causing any known issues. There was a single warning returned for image mosaic:

```
WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to set ordering between tiff readers spi
```

Comment: Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: @IanTurton The OP is edited to include the pertinent warning/error messages.